# Git: ignore files but not sub-directories in a directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a project in which all development is done at some directory depth, and so I'm used to cd-ing to a second-level directory and write some temporary files there. The tree looks like this:

```
repo
    .git/
    project/
        dev/
            important_stuff/
            more_stuff/
            README
        prod/
            important_stuff/
            more_stuff/
            README
        temp_1.txt
        test.cc
```

I would like to git-ignore exactly files that are directly in project/ - `temp_1.txt` and `test.cc` in this case. How can I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
project/*
!project/*/
```

This will ignore all files in `project` but *unignore* all directories in `project`.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to ignore:

project/temp_1.txt

project/test.cc