# Gitignore ignoring file that I want included

Tags: git

I'm working on a CMS with the structure of

```
-root
---app
----themes
-----theme_name
-------template
-------js
-------parts
-------css
```

Within Themes I have a gitignore placed

```
*
!.gitignore
!SB_Blog_Home
!README.md
```

However I've noticed that within SB_Blog_Home I can add something to the root of the theme folder and it tracks it, but all the folders are ignored. Not sure what I've done wrong here, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you question is not very clear; what output do you get when performing `git status`, and what output would you like to see?

Comment: I was getting that my branch was up to date. I was able to add the folder parts using `git add app/themes/SB_Blog_Home/parts`, but I'm not sure if I was doing it the correct way. To clarify I didn't want to track the themes folder as people could make their own and I don't want all that on the repo later down the line. The `.gitignore` file content is the second code block posted, so I'm not sure why it was ignoring the subfolders within `SB_Blog_Home`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: ignore files but not sub-directories in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428841/git-ignore-files-but-not-sub-directories-in-a-directory)

Comment: That's been added. It's a very specific question and does not help in this issue. It doesn't matter if I have `SB_Blog_Home` or `SB_Blog_Home/*/` I've also tried entering a .gitignore into the root of the theme and adding `!*` to that ignore file. I've gotten it to force tracking on my end, but not sure how that will work well if anyone tries to get on to help as there is quite apparently a big issue with my ignore file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` ignores files and folders alike.

Try instead to ignore files only, unignore folders and their content:

```
**
!.gitignore
!SB_Blog_Home/
!SB_Blog_Home/**
!README.md
```

Check what is and is not ignored with [`git check-ignore -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) (the `-v` is important):

```
git check-ignore -v -- afile
```