# Git ignore all files except particular ones

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a lot of files in directory which i wouldn't like them to be tracked by git. So i want to ignore all files except `.bashrc`, `.gitignore` and `.config/terminator/config` for example.

I'm trying to do something like this in .gitignore:

```
*
!.gitignore
!.bashrc
!.config/terminator/config
```

`.bashrc` and `.gitignore` files are unignored now but still cannot get `.config/terminator/config` unignored. How can i do this in git?

I have one possible solution but is there more elegant one without specifying subdirectories?

```
*
!.gitignore
!.bashrc
!.gitconfig

!.config/
!.config/terminator/
!.config/terminator/config
```

Comment: You've placed a not operator in front of all ignores which negates the ignoring. Remove them and try.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but if you don't want to ignore them then add them in your repo and keep them away from `.gitignore` file i.e. don't add their entry in `.gitignore` at all.

Comment: I suspect there are better duplicates of this question, but this is the (rather imperfect) one I found: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20428841/1256452

Comment: @w1n5rx i have a lot of files in directory which i wouldn't like them to be tracked by git. So it's easier to exclude all files and specify some which i would like to be tracked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short version of the answer is that once Git has ignored some *directory*, it proceeds not to bother to look *inside* that directory unless something else already forces it to do so.<sup>1</sup>  To stop this, you must explicitly list the directory or directories that you *don't* want ignored, with `!` entries:

```
*
!/.bashrc
!/.config
!.config/terminator
!.config/terminator/config
!/.gitignore
```

That is:

```
*
```

tells Git: *ignore everything unless overridden*.  Then the eventual:

```
!.bashrc
```

overrides the ignore rule for `.bashrc`, and so on.  But what Git does is that it starts by reading `.` to find all entries.  Suppose it finds them in alphabetical order: `.bashrc`, `.config`, `.editorthing`, `.gitignore`, `.history`, and so on; and suppose we have your original `.gitignore` file:

1. *Hm, I see `.bashrc`, let's check on it... ah, line 1 says ignore but 3 says don't, so don't ignore.*  Result: not ignored.
2. *Now I see `.config`, let's check on that.  Line 1 says ignore, line 2 is about `.gitignore`, line 3 is about `.bashrc`, and line 4 says to keep `.config/terminator/config`. It's not any of those, so line 1 applies!*  Result: ignored!
3. Repeat as above.

Arguably, the action in step 2 is idiotic: it's clearly impossible to apply the long rule if the shorter `.config` is ignored, so the presence of `.config/<something>` as un-ignored ought to trigger Git to un-ignore `.config`.  And in fact, the newest versions of Git try to be more clever about this, but older ones don't: you must explicitly un-ignore `.config` (or `/.config`, which is better here for reasons I won't get into, but that's why I wrote it that way above<sup>2</sup>).

There *is* a more elegant trick but it causes Git to be much slower, so you may not want to use it.  The trick is to explicitly un-ignore *all* directories:

```
*
!*/
!/.bashrc
```

and so on.  But now if you have a directory `a` with millions of sub-directories and files *within* `a`, Git will scan all `a` and all its subdirectories, whereas before, it would skip it.

---

<sup>1</sup>Having a file within `.config` in the *index* forces Git to scan `.config`.  However, you'd then run into the same issue with `.config/terminator` unless the index contained a file within `.config/terminator` as well.

<sup>2</sup>OK, I will get into it a little bit.  It does not apply in this particular case, but assuming you are un-ignoring `.bashrc`, if Git were for some reason to scan `a/`, and `a/` contained a file named `.bashrc`, Git would *not* ignore `a/.bashrc`.  We do not need the leading slash on `.config/terminator`, though, because that *contains* an *embedded* slash (one not at the end).  This makes the match on that name rooted, while matches on `.bashrc` are non-rooted and hence match `a/.bashrc`.